# How to scale BitmapData AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, matrix, scale, bitmapdata

I am editing an air application for a client, and he wants the images that you import to be scaled to 650x650 when you save them by using the code below. I tried changing the values but when the image is exported some part is missing:

```
function menuItemClick1(event:Event):void{
    var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
    mat.scale(2.0,2.0);
    var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.template_mc.width * 2, this.template_mc.height * 2, false, 0xFFFFFF);
    bmpData.draw(this.template_mc, mat);
    var _bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpData);
    _bmp.smoothing = true;
    //
    imgBytes = PNGEncoder.encode(_bmp.bitmapData);
    fs = new FileStream();
    targetFile = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("icons/image.png");
    targetFile.browseForSave("Save Your File");
    targetFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSaveSelect);
}
```

I tried changing to this with no luck:

```
mat.scale(1.0,1.0);
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(650,650, false, 0xFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate matrix scale ratio this way:

```
var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
var ratio:Number =Math.min(650/this.template_mc.width,650/this.template_mc.height);
mat.scale(ratio,ratio);
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(650, 650, false, 0xFFFFFF);
bmpData.draw(this.template_mc, mat);
```

Comment: Also, if you want your exported bitmap to be stretched (that is, not equally scaled), you can do `mat.scale(650/template_mc.width,650/template_mc.height);`, this way all of the 650x650 resultant bitmap will contain the image of the MC in question without any white borders.